# Can I set my critical battery hibernate to 1%?

Tags: laptop, battery

My new laptop is an Acer Aspire a315-51, windows 10, i3-7100u, 4 gigs RAM.

The thing goes into hibernation at 6% battery, can I reduce this to 1% safely?

Or will this reduce battery life?

Attaching image:

[image]

Comment: Are you willing to risk your data on the hope that the software is reading the charge status accurately?

Comment: What’s safe for you battery isn’t safe for your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The protection circuitry in the battery will prevent it from being dangerous undercharged, switching it off with some way to go before this point. It is **safe** to reduce that setting to 1%

Regularly allowing your battery to get as low as 5% or 1%, though, will over time stress the battery out and reduce its life. You can prolong the life of your battery by aiming to keep it between 75% and 25% as much as you can (there are some graphs at http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_prolong_lithium_based_batteries), but there are no acute safety concerns at software-reported percentages between 0% and 100%.

Comment: While it's true that it is _safe_, it's not at all uncommon for a battery to be unable to supply sufficient current at 1%. Power on my laptop for example tends to be cut off when at 3 or 4% charge.

Comment: No sure I understand...my laptop pretty much gives me 3 work sessions, 2 hours each give or take, what I do now is use it for 3 sessions till the battery dies. Fahad Sadah, are you saying I should use the laptop for 2 sessions? And then recharge to full before third session? So first session drain to 66%, second session drain to 33% and then recharge to 100% and not do 3rd session to ZERO?

Comment: Li-Ion batteries, unlike the old Ni-Mh types do not appreciate being deep-discharged. It can significantly shorten their life & even make them incapable of recharging. The battery's software will try to prevent this happening, but at risk it may just switch off half-way through saving your hibernate state.

Comment: @BrunoVincent if it's viable to do that without significantly impairing your workflow, it will increase the life of the battery - obviously at the expense of having to spend more time charging it. It's up to you to decide where you want the balance of battery life short term vs. battery longevity long term